# Many to many in asp.net mvc view and controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, many-to-many, asp.net-mvc-3, poco

How do I handle a many to many object mapping in the view and controller in the context of `users` and `roles`?

I used entity framework to map to pure POCOs like this:

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, I'd like to add a User to a role using checkboxes. I list all the roles then check one to add the user to that role. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would start by designing a view model for this scenario:

```
public class UserRolesViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<RoleViewModel> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class RoleViewModel
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public bool InRole { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

Then a roles controller:

```
public class RolesController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Edit(int userId)
    {
        // TODO: Use a repository to fetch the roles associated to the given
        // user id and then AutoMapper to map your model POCOs 
        // to a UserRolesViewModel
        var model = new UserRolesViewModel
        {
            UserId = userId,
            Roles = new[]
            {
                new RoleViewModel { RoleId = 1, InRole = false, RoleName = "Role 1" },
                new RoleViewModel { RoleId = 2, InRole = true, RoleName = "Role 2" },
                new RoleViewModel { RoleId = 3, InRole = true, RoleName = "Role 3" }
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult Update(UserRolesViewModel model)
    {
        // Here you will get the view model back containing the
        // user id and the selected roles
        // TODO: use AutoMapper to map back to a POCO and 
        // invoke the repository to update the database
        return RedirectToAction("Edit");
    }
}
```

then the Edit view (`~/Views/Roles/Edit.cshtml`):

```
@model YourAppName.Models.UserRolesViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit user roles";
}
<h2>Roles for user @Model.UserId</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Roles"))
{
    @Html.HttpMethodOverride(HttpVerbs.Put)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserId)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Roles)
    <input type="submit" value="update roles" />
}
```

and finally the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Roles/EditorTemplates/RoleViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model YourAppName.Models.RoleViewModel
<div>
    @Model.RoleName
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.RoleId)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.InRole)
</div>
```

Comment: Could you give alittle more information on this statement: `then AutoMapper to map your model POCOs to a UserRolesViewModel`

Comment: I made a new question about automapper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653163/automapper-usage